# How to find Oracle database object name from segment name?

Tags: database, oracle12c, tablespace

I have moved all my tables and indexes to other tablespaces. After the operation, all the objects from **user_tables** and **user_indexes** have the new tablespace names.

But in **user_segments**, there are still some old tablespace names:

- Partition_name:null,
- Segment_type: TABLE or INDEX,
- Segment_subtype: ASSM.

Questions:

1. Why there is no objects having old tablespace names in **user_indexes**, while some segments in **user_segments** have old tablespaces?
2. How to find out the database object names from the segments name, so that they can be moved to new tablespaces as well?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a DBA.

Anyway, see if it makes sense.

Path looks like this: table's data is in a data block > extent > segment > tablespace.

```
SQL> select t.table_name,
  2         e.extent_id,
  3         s.segment_name,
  4         s.segment_type,
  5         s.segment_subtype,
  6         s.tablespace_name
  7  from user_tables t join user_extents e on e.segment_name = t.table_name
  8  join user_segments s on s.segment_name = e.segment_name
  9  where t.table_name = 'EMP';

TABLE_NAME  EXTENT_ID SEGMENT_NAME SEGMENT_TYPE SEGMENT_SU TABLESPACE_NAME
---------- ---------- ------------ ------------ ---------- --------------------
EMP                 0 EMP          TABLE        ASSM       USERS

SQL>
```

Apparently, `segment name = table name` which means that if you want to find objects that belong to a certain tablespace, then this might be what you're looking for:

```
SQL> select s.segment_name, s.segment_type
  2  from user_segments s
  3  where s.tablespace_name = 'USERS';

SEGMENT_NAME SEGMENT_TYPE
------------ ------------
T1           TABLE
T2           TABLE
EMP          TABLE
DEPT         TABLE
<snip>
PK_SC1       INDEX
SYS_C007864  INDEX
SYS_C007928  INDEX
33 rows selected.

SQL>
```